# C++ specific type for type_info

Tags: c++, typeinfo

Consider the following methods

```
static ComponentType & getTypeFor(const type_info &t){
        ComponentType * type = componentTypes[t.hash_code()];

        if(type == NULL)
        {
            type = new ComponentType();
            componentTypes[t.hash_code()] = type;
        }
        return *type;
};

static bitset<BITSIZE> getBit(const type_info &t){
    ComponentType & type = getTypeFor(t);
    return type.getBit();
}
```

I would call this as follows

```
ComponentManagerType::getBit(typeid(MyComponentClass)); 
// Not an instance, passing class name
```

Now as the ComponentManagerType suggests; this is only meant for Components. The problem as of right now is that any type can be passed. It won't do any harm but an id and bitset will be created for a non-component object.

Q:
How can I enforce this method to accept only objects of base type Component?

I know there is no direct way. But I'm pretty much scratching my head over this.

Edit:
Added my own solution. Not sure if it's kosher.

Comment: Isn't it possible with boost:is_base_Of ?

Comment: Looks like you want to use templates instead. Unless you have very clear reason, choosing RTTI over other solutions in C++ is undesired.

Comment: GL770 as of right now I have no interest in boost.@kennyTM I figured that much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct way; `type_info` is by design a minimal interface.

I'd suggest you rewrite `getBit` as a template function callable as `getBit<MyComponentClass>()`.  You can then check base types in the template (e.g. using [boost::is_base_of](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_base_of.html); you could even enforce the requirement in the template function declaration using [std::enable_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if)) and perform the `typeid` operation knowing that the base class is correct.

Comment: I was trying something similar. Couldn't make it work. Ill try again thanks.

Comment: @Sidar Here's an example: http://ideone.com/sYl1D (although I guess libstdc++ has some problem with the usage of hash_code, it works otherwise). Also clang will give this helpful note with the error message for this code: "note: candidate template ignored: disabled by 'enable_if' [with T = NonComponent]"

Comment: Yes I figured it out myself, but your example looks good as well. As of right now I'm checking whether my typename/class is a baseclass of my component. Ill keep yours in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. Any derivative can be passed. C++ Language does not have features for this type of restriction. You can only make the method protected/private to narrow down the area of possible places of calls. In smaller scope you have better chances to control the calls.

Answer (score 0):

```
template<typename component>
static bitset<BITSIZE> getBit(){

    //Check if we are being legal with components and shizzle
    Component * c = (component*)0;

    ComponentType & type = getTypeFor(typeid(component));
    return type.getBit();
}
```

This will throw a fatal error.
If casting doesn't work.  It simply means it's not a component.

Not sure how this will fair though.

But this seems to work !